# how to derive the conditional covariance matrix of random variables (X1,X2,...,Xn)

Tags: probability-or-statistics

It is to my surprise that `Mathematica` does not have a built-in function to derive a conditional covariance matrix (CCM) for multiple random variables. Since such a matrix is very useful in statistics, I wonder anybody can develop a `code` (a `Mathematica` function to automate the derivation for given probabiity distributions) to derive a (CCM) of `n` random variables following Gaussian joint PDF.

In mathematical specification, I like to compute the following equation:

**Cov(X,Y|S) = E[XY|S] - E[X|S] E[Y|S]**

where **X**=(X1,X2,X3), **Y**=(Y1,Y2,Y3) and **S**=(S1,S2)
and the vectors **X** and **Y** have 3 RVs each and **S** is another vector with 2 RVs.

Any `code` that I can write will be very primitive, therefore I did not even try to develop one, though I can derive the above terms in the definition of CCM.